# PhantomJS - onLoadFinished called twice without reason

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Here is my code:

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var server = require('webserver').create();
var system = require('system');
var someUrl = "http://sportfun.bg";    
var port = 3000;
//Screen resolution
page.viewportSize = {
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080
};
//User agent
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    system.stderr.writeLine('Console: ' + msg);
};
var service = server.listen(port, function (request, response) {
    //console.log('Request received at ' + new Date());
    //console.log("Request" + JSON.stringify(request.post));
    var POST = request.post;
    //console.log("Bank:" + POST.bank);
    // TODO: parse `request` and determine where to go

    var step = 0;

    page.open(someUrl, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to post!');
        } else {
            console.log("Here0");    
            page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
                if(status === "success"){
                    console.log("Here 1"); 
                    response.statusCode = 200;
                    response.headers = {
                        'Cache': 'no-cache',
                        'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'
                    };

                    // TODO: do something on the page and generate `result`
                    response.write("We good");
                    //console.log(page.content);
                    response.close();  
                }
            };

        }
    });


});
console.log("Server started!");
```

I'm using PhantomJS 2.1.1.

When i launch the server and send a post request to it in the console i see strange thing:

```
Server started!
Here0
Here 1
Here 1
```

Why i see twice `Here 1` when actually the page should be once loaded ?
Is there any reason about it and how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple callbacks of `onLoadFinished` happen if there are multiple widgets embedded via iframe — like Facebook widgets or Google Maps. You can get rid of them by blacklisting calls to those sites:

```
block_urls = ['gstatic.com', 'google-analytics.com', 'tawk.to', 'perdeta.net', 'facebook.net', 'facebook.com'];

page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, request){
    for(url in block_urls) {
        if(requestData.url.indexOf(block_urls[url]) !== -1) {
            request.abort();
            console.log(requestData.url + " aborted");
            return;
        }
    }            
}
```

If you implement this solution you will notice that "Here 1" is not printed anymore. That is because the first `onLoadFinished` is actually fired even **before** `page.open` but you create it only after `page.open` is called.

If you want to make real use of page.onLoadFinished you should decalre it even before `page.open`.

Comment: And what if I don't want to abort the request? Is there a way to identify the actual page.onLoadFinished?

Comment: @LucasSteffen Yes, you can get the current URL in `onLoadFinished` with `var url = page.evaluate(function(){ return document.location.href })`

Comment: well, it didn't work, in my case the page redirected to the homepage and fired 6 times, 3 on each page, with the same address

Comment: Why not create a new question about this so we could investigate? Of course I'd need the URL to inspect though.